# How to use VSTS Build/Release to continuously integrate/deploy Docker containers to Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: docker, microservices, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm asking this question here because Azure's documentation says a sample for Linux Containers is '[coming soon](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/service-fabric-dotnet-containers)'. Anyone has any insight on when this tutorial might be available?

Meanwhile, I'm hoping someone can shed some light on how to effectively do this. 
My use case is:

- a microservices based application (say Microservices A, B, and C); each microservice should run in its own Docker container
- use Visual Studio Team Services Build capability to build container images and push them to Docker Hub
- use VSTS Release capability to **individually** deploy the microservices (containers) to a Service Fabric cluster as microservices are **independently** developed, that is, I don't want to update the entire application in Service Fabric, but only redeploy the changed microservice/container to the respective node(s)

There could be a custom solution for this where one can add Tasks to the Build and Release in VSTS (like Docker Build and Shell Script tasks), call some scripts to update the Application Manifest and Service Manifest to kick off the updates to the Service Fabric cluster, and so on.

Comment: The docker related tasks are in these extension(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Docker&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance), no way for your requirement, I think you need to build script to do it, then you can custom build task and install it to your VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Whether your containers are services in the same app or different app, you can still deploy them independently. Only changes are being applied at deployment, you don't even have to have the non-changed services in the deployment package. Look here to see an example for Service Fabric service (not in containers), but deploying containers using service manifest is conceptually the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration